# RegEx in Webpack loader exclude/include config doesn't work

Tags: webpack

I am trying to apply `babel-loader` to a specific pattern of modules, say **foo.***, under **node_modules** in addition to my app.

Other modules under **node_modules** should be skipped as usual. First I tried to use negative look-ahead didn't work:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: [
    /node_modules\/(?!foo).*/
  ],
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: {
    ...
  }
},
```

Then I splited to two loaders and didn't work either:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: [
    path.resolve(_path, "node_modules")
  ],
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: {
    ...
  }
}, 
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  include: [
    /node_modules\/foo.*/
  ],
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: {
    ...
  }
}
```

However, if I use string instead of RegEx, it works for one folder:

```
include: [
  path.resolve(_path, "node_modules/foo")
],
```

This indicates to me the **Regex** is not working as expected.

Has anyone got **RegEx** working in `Include/Exclude` field?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Turns out it's a matter of path separator in Windows, which I am using. The following negative lookahead syntax works and is OS agnostic:

```
new RegExp('node_modules\\'+path.sep+'(?!foo).*')
```

Comment: Another option would be to use an OR for os specific path separator:  
`...
exclude: [
    /node_modules(?!(\/|\\)foo)/
]
...`