# workbox webpack plugin exclude folder from precache manifest

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm using the workbox webpack plugin with vue cli 3 and I would like to exclude the files in a folder from being added to the precache manifest.

See my current file structure below

/src 
   /assets 
      /css 
      /shell
        file1.svg
        file2.svg
        file3.svg
      /svg
        file4.svg
        file5.svg
        file6.svg

I want to include the files in the shell folder in my precache manifest but I don't want to include the ones in the svg folder.

I've tried using the **globIgnores** and **exclude** options of **workboxOptions** in the **vue.config.js** file but I'm not getting the desired result.

When I tried `globIgnores: ['src/assets/svg/*']`, nothing happened as all the files are included

When I tried  `exclude: [/\.svg$/]`, it excluded the svg files in both folders.

I tried to alter the match pattern for the exclude option per below but it didn't work either:

```
exclude: [/^file4.*\.svg$/,
          /^file5.*\.svg$/,
          /^file6.*\.svg$/]
```

Answer (score 13):

I encountered a similar issue, if not the same, and was able to tease out an answer after staring at the docs here for a bit:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#generateSW-exclude

I wanted to auto-generate the precache-manifest, but exclude a particular folder along with specific filenames. So, my vue.config.js is now something like this:

```
pwa: {
  workboxOptions: {
    exclude: [
      /index\.html$/,
      /client-config\.js$/,
      /^.*folder-to-exclude\/.*$/,
    ]
  }
}
```

The **exclude/include** properties are arrays of regular expressions or strings. The reason that your expression for **exclude** picked up all *svg* files is simply that per your regex, you're looking for anything ending in *.svg*.

You might try something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    pwa: {
        appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
        appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'black',
        workboxOptions: {
            include: [
                /^.*shell\/.*$/,
            ],
            exclude: [
                /^.*svg\/.*$/,
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

Keep in mind that since we specified an **include**, we won't need to **exclude** as Webpack only grabs what you asked for under **include**. However, I added both **include/exclude** in the example above for the sake of this answer.

One way to test all this stuff w/o building over and over is to go to the root of the folder, *public* folder in my case, and run this command:

```
find .
```

This should recursively grab a list of all files/folders and return something like this:

```
.
./svg
./svg/safari-pinned-tab.svg
./svg/safari-pinned-tab-2.svg
./svg/safari-pinned-tab-1.svg
./favicon.ico
./index.html
./shell
./shell/android-chrome-192x192.png
./shell/android-chrome-512x512.png
./img
./img/icons
./img/icons/favicon-16x16.png
./img/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg
./img/icons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png
./img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png
./img/icons/apple-touch-icon.png
./img/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png
./img/icons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png
./img/icons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png
./img/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png
./img/icons/msapplication-icon-144x144.png
./img/icons/mstile-150x150.png
./img/icons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png
./img/icons/favicon-32x32.png
./robots.txt
```

Then, take that output and head over to regex101.com and try out the **include** and **exclude** expressions that match your use case. Here is an example:

[https://regex101.com/r/nzEwCz/2/](https://regex101.com/r/nzEwCz/1)

This will merely help narrow down the expression, I find, and you'll need to refine it in your IDE. I know this is a fairly verbose answer and if you have any questions just comment below.

**Note:** The expressions may be different under on a Windows box, see this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38190159/128795